# How to have SQL style aggregation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to have an `SQL` style aggregation in Python.

```
# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,2],
                   'revenue':[1,3,5,1,5],
                   'month':['2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-03-01','2014-01-01','2012-01-01']})

print(df)
   ID       month  revenue
0   1  2012-01-01        1
1   1  2012-01-01        3
2   2  2012-03-01        5
3   2  2014-01-01        1
4   2  2012-01-01        5
```

Now, I would like to calculate the total `revenue`, number of unique `months` and the first `month` for every `ID`. I get the numbers as I want, but not the column names style, as they are spread in two rows.

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'revenue':'sum','month':['nunique','first']}).reset_index()
print(df)    
  ID revenue   month            
         sum nunique       first
0  1       4       1  2012-01-01
1  2      11       3  2012-03-01
```

A normal SQL script would be something like the following pseudo code -

```
select ID, sum(revenue) as revenue, count(month) as distinct_m, first(month) as first_m from table group by ID ...
```

**My desired output:**

```
   ID    revenue  distinct_m     first_m
0  1           4           1  2012-01-01
1  2          11           3  2012-03-01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this.

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(revenue = ('revenue','sum'),
                     distinct_m = ('month','nunique'),
                     first_m = ('month','first')).reset_index()

ID    revenue  distinct_m     first_m
1         4           1  2012-01-01
2        11           3  2012-03-01
```

Comment: If you add reset_index(), you get exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let us do.

```
s=df.groupby('ID').agg(revenue = ('revenue','sum'),
                   first_m=('month','first'),
                   distinct_m =('month','nunique')).reset_index()
Out[357]: 
   ID  revenue     first_m  distinct_m
0   1        4  2012-01-01           1
1   2       11  2012-03-01           3
```

Comment: @Ch3steRc no need to apologize. Have a nice day

Comment: Your answer was same as YOBEN_S. Thanks to both of you to have spared your efforts. Your answer should stay. I am sure a good career awaits you upon entering the industry. Humility will help you always.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'revenue':'sum','month': 'first'}).reset_index()
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
df['distinct_m'] = df['month'].dt.month
print(df)

   ID  revenue      month  distinct_m
0   1        4 2012-01-01           1
1   2       11 2012-03-01           3
```

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. I want all calculations, be it max, min, count, first etc etc to be done in one aggregation step.