# Aggregation in pandas dataframe with columns names in one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I am using `Python 3.6` and I am doing an aggregation, which I have done correctly, but the column names are not in the form I want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,2],
                   'revenue':[1,3,5,1,5],
                   'month':['2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-03-01','2014-01-01','2012-01-01']})
print(df)
   ID       month  revenue
0   1  2012-01-01        1
1   1  2012-01-01        3
2   2  2012-03-01        5
3   2  2014-01-01        1
4   2  2012-01-01        5
```

Doing the aggregation below.

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'revenue':'sum','month':[('distinct_m','nunique'),('month_m','first')]}).reset_index()
print(df)
  ID revenue      month            
         sum distinct_m     month_m
0  1       4          1  2012-01-01
1  2      11          3  2012-03-01
```

**Desired output is:**

```
  ID revenue   distinct_m       month
0  1       4            1  2012-01-01
1  2      11            3  2012-03-01
```

The problem is that I am using a mixed form of expressions inside `agg()`. Had it been only `agg('revenue':'sum')`, I would have got a column named `revenue` in precisely the same format I wanted, as shown below:

```
  ID revenue 
0  1       4 
1  2      11
```

But, since I am creating 2 additional columns as well, using `tuple` form `('distinct_m','nunique'),('month_m','first')`, I get column names spread across two rows.

Is there a way to get the desired output shown above in one aggregation `agg()`? I want to avoid using tuple form for `'revenue':'sum'`. I am not looking for multiple operations afterwards to get the column names right. I am using `Python 3.6`.

Comment: you asked this exact question yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62044839/how-to-have-sql-style-aggregation-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: it's not exactly the same, but similar indeed.

Answer (score 2):

For avoid this problem is used [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) working in pandas **0.25+**, where is possible specify each columns names:

```
df = (df.groupby(['ID']).agg(revenue=('revenue','sum'),
                             distinct_m=('month','nunique'),
                             month_m = ('month','first')
                            ).reset_index())
print(df)
   ID  revenue  distinct_m     month_m
0   1        4           1  2012-01-01
1   2       11           3  2012-03-01
```

For lower pandas versions is possible flatten columns in `MultiIndex` and then `rename`:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'revenue':'sum',
                             'month':[('distinct_m','nunique'),('month_m','first')]})
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.rename(columns={'revenue_sum':'revenue',
                        'month_distinct_m':'distinct_m',
                        'month_month_m':'month_m'})
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
   ID  revenue  distinct_m     month_m
0   1        4           1  2012-01-01
1   2       11           3  2012-03-01
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same, as you suggested, but on version 3.6 it doesn't work. Also, I want to use mixed expressions like `'revenue':'sum'` where ever possible to have the same name of column and tuple where needed.

Comment: @cph_sto - I think there is pandas under 0.25.0, so not working.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I am aware of that and that's why trying something else.

Comment: @cph_sto - What are obvious reasons ;) ?

Comment: here you go sir :)

Comment: Does it also work if I want to pass some argument to the user-supplied function?